# What is the difference between POST UpdateStuff [version] and POST /api/v1/UpdateStuff in Azure AppInsights

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-application-insights

In Azure AppInsights, I can see requests from two different sources even though I have only one end point, which is /api/v1/UpdateStuff.

What is the difference between
`POST UpdateStuff [version]` and `POST /api/v1/UpdateStuff` in Azure AppInsights?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `UpdateStuff` is how your method is called in ASP.NET / c# code, and application insights tracks it as well. Should also be visible if you look at the dependency graph of a request. It is shown there as a child of /api/...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience after updating some packages. Now all request are logged as `POST UpdateStuff [version]`. 
So, I can say there is no differences only different way of logging the requests.

Comment: can you please mention which packages?

Comment: no specific one, just updating all the last versions.